# If statement across multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the data I have:

```
| total |  big  |  med  | small| big_perc | med_perc | sml_perc |
|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:----:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:| 
|   5   |   4   |   0   |   1  |   0.8    |   0.0    |   0.2    |
|   6   |   0   |   3   |   3  |   0.0    |   0.5    |   0.5    | 
|   5   |   2   |   3   |   0  |   0.4    |   0.6    |   0.0    |
```

This is what I would like to create:

```
| total |  big  |  med  | sml  | big_perc | med_perc | sml_perc | condition |   size  |
|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:----:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------:|:--------: |:--------:
|   5   |   4   |   0   |   1  |   0.8    |   0.0    |   0.2    |    YES    |   big   |
|   6   |   0   |   3   |   3  |   0.0    |   0.5    |   0.5    |    NO     |         | 
|   5   |   2   |   3   |   0  |   0.4    |   0.6    |   0.0    |    YES    |   med   |
```

For the condition column id like it to say yes if big_perc, med_perc or sml_perc is greater than 0.6 and be blank if that condition is not met.

For the size column id like it to say whichever column is greater than 0.6 or else also be blank

Here is what i've tried:

```
for (df['condition'] in len(df):

    if df['big_perc'] >= 0.60:
        df['condition'] = 'YES'
    elif df['med_perc'] >= 0.60:
        df['condition'] = 'YES'
    elif df['sml_perc'] >= 0.60:
        df['condition'] = 'YES'
    else: 
        df['condition'] = ''
```

I tried the same for/if statement for the size column

Comment: Does `pd.DataFrame.apply` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) help ?

Comment: `df['condition'] = np.where((df['big_perc'] >= 0.60) | (df['condition'] >= 0.60) | (df['sml_perc'] >= 0.60), "YES", "NO")` -- `np.where()` is good for this and is vectorized. `np.where()` is a go to for me. The `|` is the operator for "OR".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for your above dataframe:

```
df['size'] = (df.iloc[:, 4:] >= .6).dot(df.columns[4:]).str.split('_').str[0]
df['condition'] = np.where(df['size']!='', 'YES', 'NO')
```

Output:

```
   total  big  med  small  big_perc  med_perc  sml_perc size condition
1    5.0  4.0  0.0    1.0       0.8       0.0       0.2  big       YES
2    6.0  0.0  3.0    3.0       0.0       0.5       0.5             NO
3    5.0  2.0  3.0    0.0       0.4       0.6       0.0  med       YES
```

Slice you dataframe to only select the columns with the percentages, then create a boolean matrix for greater or equal to .6, then use `dot` to capture the column name for those True values.  Use string manipulation to get big, medium or small.

Answer (score 1):

For the `condition` column, [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) suffices, since it is just a single condition; however for the `size` column, since it has multiple conditions, [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) should fit in :

```
df["condition"] = np.where(df.filter(like="perc").ge(0.6).any(axis=1), "YES", "NO")

cond1 = df.filter(like="perc").gt(0.6).any(axis=1)
cond2 = df.filter(like="perc").ge(0.6).any(axis=1)
cond3 = df.filter(like="perc").lt(0.6).all(axis=1)
condlist = [cond1, cond2, cond3]
choicelist = ["big", "med", ""]

df["size"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)


    total   big med small   big_perc    med_perc sml_perc condition size
0   5        4  0   1       0.8         0.0         0.2    YES      big
1   6        0  3   3       0.0         0.5         0.5    NO   
2   5        2  3   0       0.4         0.6         0.0    YES      med
```